# Add new category to product

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

i have a script that updates all products, basically it adds a new category, the only problem is that remove the previously category that was on the product when it shouldnt, i just need to add a new category to the product.

My code:

```
 $category_id = array(49);
$_catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_productId = $_catalog->getIdBySku($sku);
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
$_product->setCategoryIds($category_id);
$_product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply merge data from getter with new ids

```
$category_id = array(49);
$_catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_productId = $_catalog->getIdBySku($sku);
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
$_product->setCategoryIds(array_merge($_product->getCategoryIds(), $category_id)
$_product->save();
```